# How to send permanently a request to my http server

Tags: sockets, http, web, webserver, httprequest

I have a http server running on my pc that I developed using C++.

I need to send permanently a request from the browser to my server (every 1s) in order to refresh my web page's content.

How can I do it?

Thanks for your help :))

Comment: Why do you want to send the request from a web browser?

Comment: because I have several images on my server and i need to send the appropriate image to the browser depending on data changes. so I need to check regularly the server if there's any changes on data and send my image. i need to do this every 1s

Comment: again, why do you want to send the request from a browser? do you want to look at the images every 1s yourself?

Comment: i need to load the appropriate image every 1s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that AJAX was designed for.  Client-side scripting can send requests, such as in a timer, to update specific areas of the page's content without reloading the entire page each time.

Otherwise, look at [HTTP server-side pushing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push) to push new data to the client whenever it changes.